# Dismissing a listview

Tags: android

I am  populating a simple listview which shows itself when i click on a button,now the code for that is

```
st.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                setlist=new  ArrayList<String>();
                setlist.add("Change Password");
                setlist.add("Change Image");
                setlist.add("Logout");
                settr=new ArrayAdapter<String>(ChatPref.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,setlist);
                llr.setAdapter(settr);
```

now I wanted to know ,what can I do dismiss this listview,as pressing back would take me to my previous activity..
any help would be greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setlist.clear(); and then settr.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**OR**

```
listView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```